# How do I observe websocket events from a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way of observing WebSocket events from an addon?

E.g. at the moment, for HTTP Requests, I might add an observer to the observer service for http-on-modify-request or http-on-examine-response topics:  I can't see any reference to WebSockets in [the list of observer notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is anything. Looking at the code, WebSockets don't send any notifications whatsoever. This might be worth filing a bug on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/, I think that they should send out at least the same `http-on-modify-request` notification as regular HTTP channels.

Answer (score 0):

I ran wireshark to check my websocket events. 
Also you can just put logs in